# Want to load button and images in same collection view cell in swift

Tags: swift, image, uicollectionview

[image]

In my app, I have to fetch the image from the gallery and show it in a collection view. In the above image there is a "+" button which is a cell in a collection view. After pressing it, it will navigate to to an image picker where i should be able to select an image from the gallery. When I am adding any image to the collection view it will add image cells to the begining of the image array, and the button should be in the last index. User interaction will be enabled for just the last index(+ button).

How to do this:-

Can I put images and buttons in the same cell, and if it is the last index then I will show the button and will make User interaction enabled? By doing this it will check every time if it is the last index or not.

Please give me any suggestions on how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done. What you should do is,

**NOTE - Before I start, the code here is untested, so you will have to make changes to suit your needs**

1. have an array that holds the images like follows

```
var imageArray: [UIImage] = [] // count is 0
```

2. have 2 custom `UICollectionViewCell`'s, one with an `UIImageView` that will show the images, and another with a 'UIButton`. For the cell with the` UIImage`, add the following lines to disable user interaction
   .

```
cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

3. Once you have done all of the above (creating an array to hold images, creating 2 custom `UICollectionViewCells`), conform to the `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate` like below

```
class ViewController: ViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return imageArray.count + 1 
       //Add + 1 so that there will always be atleast on cell, which will be your button cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        // This will show the button cell if the condition is met
        // If not, it will show the image cell
        if indexPath.row == imageArray.count - 1 || indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ButtonCell", for: indexPath) as! ButtonCell
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCell
            // Setting image to the cell
            cell.image = imageArray[indexPath.row - 1]
            return cell
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // This condition will make sure that the Button cell is the only one that 
        // invokes showImagePicker() when you click on any cell
        if indexPath.row == imageArray.count - 1 {
            showImagePicker()
        }
    }
}
```

Note here that I have added a `+1` to the number of items. That is to always show the cell with the button, as it will always show at least 1 cell.

Another thing is to dequeue the cell, you will have to add some conditions to show either the button cell or the image cell.

4. The final step is to get images from the gallery using a `UIImagePickerController`, adding it to the array and finally calling the `collectionview.reloadData()` method to reload you collection view. If you want a good resource to learn about `UIImagePickerController` check [THIS TUTORIAL](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/10/4/importing-photos-with-uiimagepickercontroller) on Hacking with Swift